# Kotlin static functions : companion object, @JvmStatic @JvmField

Tags: android, static, kotlin

I have just started messing around with the Kotlin programming language, which is pretty much cooler than Java. I have some doubts related to static methods and fields:

**Q1: Official document says**

> Kotlin can also generate static methods for functions defined in named
>   objects or companion objects if you annotate those functions as
>   @JvmStatic.

But if you see below I can access `bar()` method as a static method, which works without using `@JvmStatic` annotation. But on official doc its throwing error -> [Kotlin static method](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods).

```
Class C{
    companion object{
        @JvmStatic
        fun foo() { }
        fun bar();
    }
}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    C.foo();
    C.bar(); //this line works fine
}
```

**Q2: Do I really need `@JvmStatic` and `@JvmField` to make things static?**
As you can see with `companion` object, things are working as expected.

Comment: @user8371915 well i have removed the image of code. Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can access members of a `companion object` as `C.bar()` **in Kotlin**, but not in Java. Without `@JvmStatic`, you would need to use `C.Companion.bar()` **in Java**, just as said in the docs.

Note that, without `@JvmStatic`, the function is compiled to an instance (non-static) method that is called on `C.Companion` in Java (and Kotlin simply shortens it to a call on `C`, but it's the same under the hood), so yes, you need either `@JvmStatic` and `@JvmField` to make a declaration in a companion object compile into a static member.

Basically, `@JvmStatic` and  `@JvmField` are tools for Java interoperation that help with creating Java-friendly APIs, and if you don't need to call the Kotlin members from Java (e.g. they are internal to your Kotlin project, or you are developing a library that is unlikely to be used with Java), you can leave them as they are.

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way the resulting Java code differs when using `@JvmStatic` vs `@JvmField`?

Comment: @Joschua, with `@JvmStatic`, it's the property accessors that will be made static, but `@JvmField` will instead expose the static backing field and instruct the compiler not to generate the accessors at all. Note also that `@JvmField` is suitable for instance properties, which are, then, compiled to non-static fields.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you do need `@JvmStatic`. The problem with your code that you call it **in Kotlin** while in documentation code was called **in Java**.

To be more precise, this code won't compile:

```
public void main(String[] args) {
    C.foo(); // Ok
    C.bar(); // Not ok
}
```

Kotlin knows about function in `companion object` so you can call it on class directly, while Java doesn't know anything about it. So you annotate any function with `@JvmStatic` and it becomes visible from Java code as static method.

And just to clarfiy - purpose of `@JvmStatic` is interop with Java code. If you write your application in Kotlin only you don't need `@JvmStatic` at all.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation ("page 2") refers to the case where you call the function from Java, not Kotlin.

When you only use Kotlin, there is no need for the annotation. Instead use the way you declared your bar() method. So you can call `C.bar()`